# Closed Bounded Intervals and Uniform Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

For this Theorem, the proof on my course notes is like:

> Suppose, for a contradiction,that $f: [a,b] \to \mathbf R$ is continuous but not uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$.
>   Choose $\epsilon \gt 0$ so that for all $\delta \gt 0$ there exisit $x,y \in [a,b]$ such that $|x - y| \le \delta$ but $|f(x) - f(y)| \gt \epsilon$. Thus for each $k \in \mathbb Z^{+}$ choose $x_{k},y_{k}\in[a,b]$ with $|x_{k}-y_{k}| \le \frac{1}{k}$ and $|f(x_{k}) -f(y_{k})|\gt \epsilon$
>   By the Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem, we can choose a convergent subsequence $(y_{k_{j}})_{k_{j}}$ of $(y_{k})_k$} . Let $c = \lim_{j \to \infty}y_{k_{j}}$. For all $j$ we have $|x_{k_{j}} - y_{k_{j}}| \le \frac{1}{k_{j}}$,hence by sequeeze theorem we have $x_{k_{j}} \to c$.
>   Since $f$ is continuous at $c$ and $x_{k_{j}} \to c$, $y_{k_{j}} \to c$, we have $f(x_{k_{j}}) \to f(c) ,f(y_{k_{j}}) \to f(c)$ so that $|f(x_{k_{j}}) - f(y_{k_{j}})| \le \epsilon$ giving a contradiction.

I just don't understand why this proof only holds for **Closed Interval** ? Or where we used some special properties of **Closed Interval** in the above proof?
Can someone help me? Thansk!

Comment: If the interval is not closed, the result doesn't hold. For example, $f(x)=\frac1x$ in $(0,1)$ is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: Yes but in the proof we didn't use any properties of closed interval right？

Answer (score 3):

If you apply the proof to open interval $(a, b) $ then there may be a possibility that the common limit $c$ is an end-point $a$ or $b$ and thus lies outside the interval of consideration. In that case we can't say that $f$ is continuous at $c$ and the sequences $f(x_{k_j}), f(y_{k_j}) $ may not necessarily tend to $f(c) $.

BTW it's great that you asked this question. The proof in your question really does not emphasize anywhere about the closed interval thing.

Answer (score 0):

> Please see *Paramanand Singhs* answer for a more detailed and correct exposition.

---

Necessary for the application of the Bolzano-Weierstraß Theorem is that the sequence of question is bounded. But this can only happen if $[a,b]$ is a closed interval, making this condition necessary too (otherwise there might be unbounded sequences, ruining the proof). So, the fact that $f$ is defined on a closed bounded interval enables us to use the Bolzano-Weierstraß Theorem here.

**EDIT:** More important, the declared limit of the given subsequences might not be within the interval, if its not closed.

Comment: The interval $(a, b) $ is also bounded. There is no problem applying Bolzano-Weierstrass here. The issue is that $c$ may lie in $(a, b) $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Could you elaborate?

Comment: Let the sequences $x_k, y_k$ take values from open interval $(a, b) $. Then by Bolzano-Weierstrass each of them has a convergent subsequence. Thus let $x_{k_j} \to c$ as $j\to\infty$. Now it is quite possible that $c=a$ or $c=b$ so that $c\notin(a, b) $ and the argument of question cannot be continued further in this case.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Ah, okay. Thank you kindly. It seems like I have misunderstood something quite crucial.